# Oracle SQL DROP CREATE TABLESPACE error

Tags: database, oracle, tablespace, sql-drop

so im trying to drop a tablespace temp with the command

```
DROP TABLESPACE temp INCLUDING CONTENTS;
```

but i get this error: tablespace 'temp' does not exist. however when i try and create the tablespace with this command

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
TEMPFILE 'C:/Oracle/oradata/orcl/temp.dbf'
SIZE 400M REUSE
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED EXTENT
MANAGEMENT LOCAL;
```

i get this error: 'cannot add file... - file already apart of database'.
anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the file is already part of the database, but part of a tablespace named something other than temp.

What do you get from the following query:

```
select tablespace_name from dba_data_files where file_name = 'C:/Oracle/oradata/orcl/temp.dbf'
union all
select tablespace_name from dba_temp_files where file_name = 'C:/Oracle/oradata/orcl/temp.dbf';
```

Comment: it returns: no rows selected

Comment: Does the file 'C:/Oracle/oradata/orcl/temp.dbf' exist in the filesystem?  Are any other databases running on the server?  If so, try running the query above on all the databases installed on the server.

Comment: your insights are correct. i remember i mistyped something along the way and i tried to guess my mistyped word and i was able to drop it and also create.. thank you